# I can't export html table to Excel xls format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, export-to-excel

I'm using table2excel jQuery plugin to export table to .xls format
but when I export it it exports in .xls but when I open it using Microsoft Office Excel its gives "can't open the file",
then I open it using Google Office on Google Drive 
it opens it correctly but using Google Word.

I want to open the file on Office Excel. 
This is my code:

```
$('#excel').click(function(){
        $("#tables").table2excel({
          exclude: ".table",
              name: "Worksheet Name",
              filename: "Rapor",
              fileext: ".xls",
              exclude_img: true,
              exclude_links: true,
              exclude_inputs: true


        });
    });

<table class="table" id="tables">
                        <thead class="thead-inverse">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Mağaza Adı</th>
                                <th>ID No</th>
                                <th>Ariza Sınıfı</th>
                                <th>İş Tipi</th>
                                <th>Tarih</th>
                                <th>Malzeme Kodu</th>
                                <th>Malzeme Adi</th>
                                <th>Miktar</th>
                                <th>Birim</th>
                                <th>Fiyat</th>
                                <th>Toplam Fiyat</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
         </table>
```

Comment: try open Excel  go to-> file -> options -> trust center -> trust center settings -> protected view : check all checkboxes and restart excel.

Comment: its works  thanks for you

Comment: put it as solution and i will check it for  you

Comment: Thanks E-housma Mardini

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Excel
go to:
<kbd>file</kbd> -> <kbd>options</kbd> -> <kbd>trust center</kbd> -> <kbd>trust center settings</kbd> -> <kbd>protected view</kbd> and check all checkboxes and restart excel.

Hope this helps.